# Is this a correct proof that all groups of order $35$ are Abelian?

Tags: group-theory

Is this a correct proof that all groups of order $35$ are Abelian?

Suppose we have a group $G$ of order $35=5\cdot7$. Then we can easily apply Sylow's theorems to deduce that the Sylow $5$ and Sylow $7$ subgroups are unique.

We proceed with a counting argument.

Since $|G|=35$ then the only possible orders of elements are $1,5,7,35$. (Indeed since $o(g)=\langle g \rangle | 35$ by Lagrange's theorem). Let us consider the Sylow $7$ subgroup it contains the identity and $6$ remaining elements of order $7$.

Thus supposing we have no elements of order $35$ the remaining $35-1-6=28$ elements must have order $5$ but this is not possible as there is only one Sylow $5$ group so there are only $4$ elements with order $5$. Hence the remaining $28-4=24$ elements must have order $35$ in particular and of these elements generate $G$ and so $G$ is cyclic and hence Abelian.

Of course I did leave out a few details that are quite trivial to show but does the argument hold in principle?

Comment: Yes, the argument holds in principle.

Comment: Using Sylow to count the number of elements in $G$ which aren't of degree $|G|$, and see that there aren't enough of them is a valid tactic (in this form it is restricted to when $|G|$ is the product of two primes), and in this case it worked. That's all we ask for in any proof.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument seems correct in principle. This is an instantiation of the following more general result. If a group $G$ is of order $|G|=pq$ for primes $p$ and $q$ with $p<q$ and $p$ not dividing $q-1$, then $G$ is abelian. A quick way to see this is to note that the Sylow subgroups are unique (as you mentioned), and in fact these account for all subgroups (why?). This means that all subgroups must be normal, and thus any semi-direct product isomorphic to $G$ degenerates into a direct product, making $G$ abelian.